# What event is fired when component is drawn on the screen

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Using Flex SDK 4.14.1.

What event is fired when a component comes into view after scrolling a scroller?

I have a mobile app with a scroller component and it has a lot of items (about 4 screens worth of data), now I was wondering if a particular event was fired when these components came into view (drawn on the screen)?

What I want to do is dispatch an event when we get to a certain point down the 'page', but I cannot see any way to do this. I have tried creationComplete, show and addedToStage but they all seem to fire when the view is created, what I want is a solution something like the List component where items are rendered just before they are drawn on the screen.

Any suggestions greatly welcomed as dispatching these events at the start would both be a total waste of bandwidth, and a drain on resources that are valuable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in summary, there isn't one? Ah, ok, well that's fair enough.

I ended up putting a -load more- button in and calling my commands from that, works perfectly.

I am asking Apache to put in an event when an item is rendered on the screen, who the hell wants to load all of their data at start?